# How to loop through an ArrayList within a custom Object?

Tags: java, loops, object, arraylist

I realize that variations of this question have been asked before, but I am having a uniquely difficult time figuring out how to complete the following task:

I have an object that looks something like this (please note, "Skill" and "Certification" are **ENUMS**):

```
Public Employee {

String name;
List<Skill> employableSkills = new ArrayList<>();
List<Certification> certifications = new ArrayList<>(); 
   ...
}
```

In another class, I've got a

```
List<Employee> listOfEmployees;
```

and I'm trying to loop through it like this:

```
// determine the total number of employees who know Java

int numberOfEmployeesWhoKnowJava = 0;

for (Employee employee : listOfEmployees) {
    if (employee.employableSkills.contains( ?? )) {

numberOfEmployeesWhoKnowJava++;
}
```

I'm struggling to get the exact syntax on the if-statement. I have tried this:

```
if(employee.employableSkills.contains(Employee.EmployableSkills.JAVA)) {
```

but EmployableSkills in this string gets "cannot resolve symbol."

How should I loop through the List on each Employee object and check if it contains JAVA?

**Edit: It turns out I was making a fundamental error. In OOP, it is best not to expose the data from one class to another class. Instead, I wrote getters in the Employee class, then called those getters from my other class. That way, the data in Employee is not directly exposed to the class that needed it.**

Comment: Can you share the definition of that enum Skill?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you get syntax right, the following code will have a bad complexity of order n - O(n).

```
if(employee.employableSkills.contains(Employee.EmployableSkills.JAVA)) {
```

Change you List to hash implementation of set

```
Set<Skill> employableSkills = new HashSet<>();
```

and now loop through the employees

```
int numberOfEmployeesWhoKnowJava = 0;
for (Employee employee : listOfEmployees) {
  if (employee.employableSkills.contains(Skill.JAVA)) {
     numberOfEmployeesWhoKnowJava++;
  } 
}
```

This will give a complexity of O(1) while looking skills

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but if my interpretation is correct, try this:

```
if (employee.employableSkills.contains(Skill.JAVA))
```

Comment: This gives me the same issue: "Cannot resolve symbol: Skill"

Comment: @Umbrella_Programmer Import it.

Comment: Like I said your question is a little unclear, @Umbrella_Programmer, please post **EVERYTHING**